# change selected item in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have an input-field configured with jQuery autocomplete. The `autocomplete` works fine and the values are displayed fine. Imagine when I enter "hello" in the input field, autocomplete displays a list with: "hello john", "hello mary", "hello xyz". When I select one of the displayed options ,"hello john" for instance, usually "hello john" would be displayed in the input field. But I want to modify that string so that only "john" is displayed. When I try to do this in the `select` event, setting the input with `$(this).val("john");` it doesn't work.

EDIT:

As I experienced, the input value changes for a small period of time (time between the `$(this).val(hotel);` call and the the end of the `select` part). Then it's overwritten by the original value proposed by the autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {

  //// do here
  ////write /////
   return false;//// in last line
}
});
```

as per doumentation http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: thanks, this works nice. I hope returning false won't have any side-effects :)

Answer (score 1):

**fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/8ptJv/1/**

**html:**

```
<input type="text" id="tags"/>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Hello John",
      "Hello tommy",
      "Hello Mary",
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value.replace("Hello ",""));
            return false;
        }
    });
  });
```